# Sencha carousel implementation in android

Tags: android, carousel, swipe

Can anyone let me know how to implement this feature specified at

http://vimeo.com/24475654

Specially i am interested to know how to give dots below images which get changed when we swipe the images. Is there inbuilt function or any open source to implement this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is by using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) from android support package. Here is a tutorial on how to use it: [Android User Interface Design: Horizontal View Paging](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/)

As for the 'dots' below you can refer to this custom library for a `ViewPager` indicator: [JakeWharton / Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: how can i implement dot feature?

Comment: You can use one of the libraries for ViewPager indicators. I recommend this one: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native `Gallery` to do this and extend it to look like the one you want.
It has on selected item listeners so you can simply select the dots that correspond to the selected items.

Here is a Gallery tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html