# Drag and Drop from Carousel Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am working on an application which is having Carousel implementation for the listings.

[image]

Now I need to drag a particular item image from the Carousel and need to drop it on the bottom bucket. I have got documents regarding Carousel and Drag and drop functionality in Android from the following links :

[Sencha carousel implementation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040895/sencha-carousel-implementation-in-android)

[Carousel view implementation like listview scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942443/carousel-view-implementation-like-listview-scrolling)

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html   etc.

But I am still not getting any options for Drag and Drop from Carousel. Please any one suggest me some better links for this functionality.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can I know how do you store your items for both view types and what type of view is it?

Comment: I am using Bitmaps since both should contain only images..

Comment: I mean are your view's list? are your items stored as an arraylist? what operation do you want to do after the item has been dropped into the bottom?

Comment: Yes, the image is loaded from URL using custom image loader.  When user drag the item to bottom bucket, we should put a thumbnail of the same.  This can be created dynamically, but the drag functionality is the issue since only the Carousel touch is handled.

Comment: Do you need to remove image from Carousel when user drops it in the buttom?

Comment: No, the image needs to be kept in the Carousel.

Comment: Or else I can load the image again from same URL after drag event..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32065/discussion-between-timson-and-milanix)